# Using bash for tcp connections

Tags: bash, tcp

In order to redirect the tcp connections with bash, why the following commands return nothing?

```
[root@rocks7 ~]# echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n" > /dev/tcp/yahoo.com/80
[root@rocks7 ~]# printf "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n" > /dev/tcp/google.com/80
[root@rocks7 ~]#
```

Comment: Because you are sending but not reading?

Comment: If you want to receive too, install `socat` and try something like `echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\n\n" | socat STDIO TCP:google.com:80`

Answer (score 4):

You need to open the connection for read and write, using `<>`, and probably send a few more headers, then read the reply. For example,

```
exec 5<>/dev/tcp/yahoo.com/80
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: yahoo.com\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\n\r" >&5
# get reply:   HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently^M
cat <&5
```

I used arbitrary file descriptor 5 just to avoid clobbering the standard 0, 1, and 2. With yahoo you don't need the content length header, but other sites might not reply until they have received more input. yahoo does require the host header, or you will get the reply `HTTP/1.1 400 Host Header Required`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to meuth's answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440053/380936

Don't forget to close the socket after you are done talking to the remote server:

```
exec 5>&-
```

You may also want adding `Connection: close`, e.g.:

```
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: yahoo.com\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r" >&5
```